# Read value from frida hooked native method Jlong parameter

Tags: android, ghidra, function-hooking, frida, shared-object

I am new to using frida for hooking native android code i.e lib.so, so I have load the lib into ghidra and can find the native function. the native function is getting 5 params including jnienv and jclass but I wanted to get the value of Jlong and read it. this is the snippet of the function in ghidra.

```
undefined Java_com_myapp_sMessage
                    (JNIEnv *env,jclass thiz,jlong a0,jobject a1,jobject a2)

{
  Message aMStack_200 [448];
  undefined **local_40;
  jobject local_3c;
  undefined ***local_30;
  int local_24;
  
  local_24 = __stack_chk_guard;
  if (a0._4_4_ == (jobject)0x0) {
    local_3c = (jobject)0x0;
  }
  else {
    local_3c = (*(*env)->NewGlobalRef)(env,a0._4_4_);
  }
... //the code is so long and I thought is so irrelevant to my question right now
```

so I have wrote this frida code to hook that native function.

```
 Interceptor.attach(
        Module.getExportByName(
          "libca.so",
          "Java_com_myapp_sMessage"
        ),
        {
          onEnter: function (args) {
            console.log(
              "Entered Java_com_myapp_sMessage"
            )
            console.log(
              "args[0]=" +
                args[0] +
                " , args[1]=" +
                args[1] +
                " , args[2]=" +
                args[2] +
                " , args[3]=" +
                args[3] +
                " , args[4]=" +
                args[4]
            )
            // this.context.x0=0x1;
          },
          onLeave: function (retval) {
            console.log(
              "Exited Java_com_myapp_sMessage, retval:" +
                retval
            )
            // retval.replace(0x1);
          },
        }
      )
```

but when I run the frida script it print out value for the params like: args[0]=0xab8f6e40 , args[1]=0xa956e7bc , args[2]=0xd68cf000 , args[3]=0x6246564 , args[4]=0xa956e7c0.

so in this case Jlong a0 corresponds to args [2] if I am not wrong. and in the android I know the a0 value is `558750103159846912` so in the native side I tried to print args [2] just log or see the same value but did not succeeded because it prints that hex values `args[2]=0xd68cf000`

so I have tried on `args[2].readfromcstring()` or `args[2].toint32()` also when I tried to use `Memory.readByteArray(ptr(args[2]), 64)` it print out `args[2]=[object ArrayBuffer]`. so how can I print the value passed to this parameter?

edit:

added ARM disassembly of the function:

```
                                 ********************************************
                                 *                          FUNCTION                           *
                                 ********************************************
                                 undefined1 __stdcall Java_com_myapp_sMessage
                                     assume LRset = 0x0
                                     assume TMode = 0x1
               undefined1           r0:1                             <RETURN>
               JNIEnv *                r0:4                             env
               jclass                     r1:4                             thiz
               jlong                     Stack[0x0]:8               a0                                           XREF[1]:           001c74fa(R)  
               jobject                   r2:4                             a1
               jobject                   r3:4                             a2
               undefined4           Stack[-0x24]:4            local_24                                  XREF[2]:           001c7508(W), 
                                                                                                                                                        001c7558(R)  
               undefined4           Stack[-0x30]:4            local_30                                  XREF[1]:           001c752e(W)  
               undefined4           Stack[-0x3c]:4            local_3c                                  XREF[1]:           001c7530(W)  
               undefined4           Stack[-0x40]:4            local_40                                  XREF[1]:           001c7538(W)  
                                 Java_com_myapp_sMessage                                  XREF[1]:   Entry Point(*)  
      001c74ec f0 b5            push                             {r4,r5,r6,r7,lr}
     001c74ee 03 af            add                               r7,sp,#0xc
      001c74f0 2d e9 00      push                             {r8,r9,r11}
                      0b
      001c74f4 f8 b0            sub                               sp,#0x1e0
      001c74f6 04 46           mov                              r4,env
      001c74f8 22 48           ldr                                env,[DAT_001c7584]                                                                                                                        = 00434A5Eh
      001c74fa d7 e9 02      ldrd                              r8,thiz,[r7,#a0]
                      81
....  //the code is so long and I thought is so irrelevant to my question right now
```

Comment: `jlong` is identical to the C data type `long` (64 bit signed) so a function call argument should passed as a "by value" argument (not by reference). As the argument values in your question are pretty low (e.g. 0xa956e7bc) I assume you are using a 32bit app/device. I am not sure how a 64bit value is passed by value in a function call. In such a case, may be it is split into two 32bit values?

Comment: @Robert, correct I am using 32bit device as it is arm v7 architecture. I have added the assembly code but I can't understand if the values of jlong is splitted into two registers.

Comment: According to the disassembly you have added it seems that the jlong parameter is passed on the stack, instead of a register. Not sure how Frida handles this situation.

Comment: well Frida provides `this.context.sp` but either did not give the output I was looking for. I mean when I tried to log `" , this.context.sp =" + this.context.sp.add(0x0)`  it outputs ` this.context.sp =0xa99067a8` well I am not sure if I was right using `this.context.sp` it is stack pointer but not so clear how I can reach `jlong                     Stack[0x0]:8               a0` in this case.

Comment: My guess would be `this.context.sp.readLong()`

Comment: well this logs `this.context.sp.readLong() =-1402419264` whilst I am sure was passed the integer value I have mention in the above which is `558750103159846912`

Comment: @Robert, I am still struggling with this. what other alternatives can I do to go further.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use an arm64 device, then you would not have to face such problems. armv7 Android device are outdated anyway.

Comment: well I have switched to armv8a device. running the script while logging the args I am getting `args[0]=0xb4000072f85c43c0 , args[1]=0x73a071ee10 , args[2]=0x6246564d68cf000 , args[3]=0x7248516720 , args[4]=0x7248516724` when I tried to apply `readLong()` on `args[2]` I am getting this error `Error: access violation accessing 0x246564d68cf000`

Comment: can this be a kind  of memory protection by the program?

Comment: No, on arm64 the value should be directly passed in via a register, so no stack is involved. This is the reason you get access violation. That was the reason I recommended to switch to armv8a. Not sure why you don't see the expected value.

Comment: I have used also `this.context.x2.readLong` same error `access violation accessing 0x246564d68cf000 ` here it is the script and the native code snippet look it please https://pastebin.com/vc65j2GL